# Extracting significance from (WaveletComp) wavelet in R

Tags: r, time-series, wavelet

I am using the R package WaveletComp for spectral analysis of a time series.
after fitting my data with:

```
WVT <- analyze.wavelet(Fits_16s_10C, "FvFm",
                     method = "white.noise",
                     loess.span = 0, 
                     dt = 1, dj = 1/500,
                     lowerPeriod = 2, upperPeriod = 36,
                     make.pval =TRUE, n.sim = 100)
```

I used the analyze.wavelet in:

```
reconstruct(WVT, siglvl = 0.05)
```

to produce a reconstructed time series constrained by the significance of wavelet power

[WVT_reconstruct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNwFp.png)

This plot seems to show the point of my time series where the wavelet is no longer significant. However, I cannot extract that point from the large analyze.wavelet.

I tried converting the analyze.wavelet$power.pval matrix to a data frame. This returns a data frame of 2085 rows(the number of Fourier periods) and 32 columns(the number of observations).

However, I'm not sure how to extract the number used in the reconstructed plot from this.